# Is there any way to run an Alexa app for Echo/Dot on a local connection and connect to a private server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, alexa-skills-kit

I'm designing a skill that my company is trying to test. I am connected to VPN and can access my company's servers through it, but I am unsure if I can do this with the Amazon products. Is there a way to run the Alexa app and be able to connect locally to the network?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do so . Alexa needs to access to amazon to be able to work. and if your local server have not an external Ip address It can't be reached by alexa skill hosted of course in the cloud.